# create_account_success remove standard address zencart

Tags: templates, zen-cart, webshop

I want to remove the 'Standard Address' fieldset on the page `create_account_success` in a zencart webshop...

Does anybody have a clue where I can remove this in the application files? Or have a clue where I can set this address? The fieldset is shown without any content ...

Answer (score 0):

In the purest sense, you could hack that code out of the tpl_create_account_success_default.php template file.

BUT the REAL problem isn't the template. The REAL problem is that you've got no address to display, which should never happen. So that tells me you've got a number of other changes going on which you've not disclosed here.